# Capistrano run local command exit on failure

Tags: capistrano

I would like to run local commands and exit on failure of any command. whats the best way to do this with capistrano? run_locally will continue going on failure.

Do i have to check the last commands exist status everytime (or create a custom run locally function)?

Answer (score 2):

I had to create my own function like this:

```
task :build_backend do
  run_local("echo hello")
  run_local("abcdef")
  run_local("echo 'not run'")
end

def run_local(cmd)
  system cmd
  if($?.exitstatus != 0) then
    puts 'exit code: ' + $?.exitstatus.to_s
    exit
  end
end
```

Using [this](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Process/Status.html)

Answer (score 0):

Generally in shell you can run multiple commands the way you want by `command1 --some-argument foo && command2 && command3`. the `&&` operator will cause, that the chain will stop when one command fails (returns non-zero return value).